# Visual studio code is highlighting as an error a working code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, opencv

I am using visual studio code and when i do these basic lines of code
`import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)`

vs highlights them as errors saying that "Module 'cv2' has no ['imread' \ 'imshow' \ 'waitKey'] member" although when I run the code its working.

What can I do?

Comment: what linter do you use? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

Comment: pylint I think. Because it says that the error is a pylint error

Comment: Try adding `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2"]` to VSCode settings. It will whitelist cv2.

Comment: Where should I add this in the settings?